# I have a error when i use parseFIle function with pdfparser

Tags: php, pdf, pdfparser

I wan't to parse a file with : https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser

## **The problem**

When i use `$parser->parseFile($pathToPdf)` I got this :

```
Argument 1 passed to Smalot\PdfParser\Parser::parseHeader() must be of the type array, string given, called in /path/to/project/vendor/smalot/pdfparser/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php on line 266
```

this only happens with some files but not all.

if you need more details please let me know

## Complete code

```php
$parser = new PdfParser();
$pdf = $parser->parseFile($path);
```

## **Details**

- PHP version : 7.4
- used library : https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser

Comment: Because this problem is related to a very specific library, and also doesn't happen for all files, you might be better off creating an issue and posting a problematic PDF here: https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/issues

Comment: This bug seems to have been fixed by dev can you tell if you’re Using the latest version of this package? Reference: https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/pull/518

Comment: no that pull request was closed and not merged

Comment: https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/issues/557 that my issue